# Unable to test code that uses coroutines and suspend functions with Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm trying to write an app using MVP and adapting the asynchronous Repository pattern I'm used to write in Java to use Kotlin's suspend functions. I haven't, however, been able to properly test code that uses suspend functions. The further I got was having tests run and fail from what I believe is the mock not returning the object it was supposed to, but null instead.

Here's a small app that shows the problem:

The `UserRepository` (the `getUser()` method alternates between returning a dummy User and throwing an exception):

```
interface UserRepository {
    suspend fun getUser(): User
}

class UserRepositoryImpl : UserRepository {

    var shouldWork = false

    override suspend fun getUser(): User {

        shouldWork = !shouldWork

        if (shouldWork) {
            return User("Mr. User", "user@example.com")
        } else {
            throw UnableToFetchUserInfoException()
        }

    }
}
```

The View:

```
interface MainView {
    fun showUserInfo(user: User)
    fun hideUserInfo()
    fun showFailedToLoadUserInfoIndicator()
    fun hideFailedToLoadUserIndicator()
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MainView {

    private lateinit var presenter: MainPresenter

    override fun showUserInfo(user: User) {
        userInfo.text = user.toString()
    }

    override fun hideUserInfo() {
        userInfo.text = ""
    }

    override fun showFailedToLoadUserInfoIndicator() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to get user info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun hideFailedToLoadUserIndicator() {
        // nothing to do. It's a toast.
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        presenter = MainPresenterImpl(this, UserRepositoryImpl(), UI)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            presenter.onFetchUserButtonClicked()
        }

    }


}
```

The Presenter:

```
interface MainPresenter {
    fun onFetchUserButtonClicked()
}

class MainPresenterImpl(private val view: MainView,
                        private val userRepository: UserRepository,
                        private val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext) : MainPresenter {

    override fun onFetchUserButtonClicked() {
        launch(coroutineContext) {
            view.hideFailedToLoadUserIndicator()
            try {
                val user = userRepository.getUser()
                view.showUserInfo(user)
            } catch (ex: UnableToFetchUserInfoException) {
                view.hideUserInfo()
                view.showFailedToLoadUserInfoIndicator()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and the test:

```
@Test
fun `should show user info on the view when the user request finishes succesfully`() = runBlocking {
    presenter = MainPresenterImpl(viewMock, userRepositoryMock, CommonPool)

    val expectedUser = User("Test", "test@testaing.com")

    whenever(runBlocking { userRepositoryMock.getUser() } ).thenReturn(expectedUser)
    presenter.onFetchUserButtonClicked()
    verify(viewMock, times(1)).showUserInfo(expectedUser)

}
```

Which outputs...

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
mainView.showUserInfo(
    User(name=Test, email=test@testaing.com)
);
-> at com.pablobr9.suspendwithtests.MainPresenterImplTest$should show user info on the view when the user request finishes succesfully$1.doResume(MainPresenterImplTest.kt:40)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
mainView.showUserInfo(
    null
);
-> at com.pablobr9.suspendwithtests.MainPresenterImpl$onFetchUserButtonClicked$1.doResume(MainPresenterImpl.kt:15)
```

I have tried a lot of things but I still haven't been able to write a testable MVP app using suspend functions / coroutines in Kotlin. Can't even do it with one as simple as this one. What am I missing here?

Comment: actually, your code works fine for me. My guess is, that your `userRepositoryMock` is a property with a custom getter. Is that right?

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: The code looks mostly correct and should work.
However it's better to replace

    `whenever(runBlocking { userRepositoryMock.getUser() } ).thenReturn(expectedUser)`

with

    `whenever(userRepositoryMock.getUser()).thenReturn(expectedUser)`


You can also improve the question by reducing the scope of the example to a couple of classes with one suspending method in each to demonstrate the issue so more people can understand it.
The current example is a bit too verbose and yet incomplete (e.g. lacking User class) so it can't be copy-pasted for testing.

Answer (score -2):

The fix is already in the mockito lib, https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/pull/171

Verify that you have `mockito-core` **explicitly** into your dependencies list too, for example:

```
dependencies {
    // other dependencies...
    // mockito...
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.0"
    // mockito kotlin...
    testImplementation "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0"
}
```